# Echoing something with multiple quotes and key characters (&, $, !, etc.)

Tags: shell-script, quoting, echo

Let's say you have to echo this into a file:

```
RZW"a4k6[)b!^"%*X6Evf
```

How do you do it?

My actual "line" to echo is a 2048 characters line.

Comment: You're planning to type `echo` *`2048 random nonsense chars here`*? I suspect it comes from a file or is generated somehow, yes?

Comment: @mikeserv , yes. Actually I was trying to make gpg read the passphrase from a file descriptor. Didn't know there was an option for that. My initial "stupid" idea was to echo the passphrase by using an alias in .bash_aliases.

Comment: Not stupid, just the wrong question.

Answer (score 6):

Just put it in single quotes:

```
echo 'RZW"a4k6[)b!^"%*X6Evf' > file
```

But if you have any single quotes in the string you need to escape each of those in double quotes (`"'"`) and "glue" the result together like this:

```
echo 'text without single quotes'"'"'and other text without single quote'
```

Answer (score 6):

For arbitrary content, you can also use:

```
cat << 'EOF' > file
RZW"a`4$k6[)b!^"'%*X6Evf
RZW"a`4$k6[)b!^"'%*X6Evf
EOF
```

(as long as that content doesn't contain lines that consist of exactly `EOF`, in which case you can use a different delimiter).

To include NUL characters (`^@` usually entered with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+@</kbd>), the above will only work with `zsh`. With other shells (and `zsh`), you can do:

```
cat > file
```

Enter the text and hit <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> on an empty line (or <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> twice if you want to include a non-terminated line) when finished.

Another approach to deal with arbitrary, potentially binary data is to use things like `uuencode` or `base64`:

For instance:

```
 printf '\0\1\2\3' > file
```

Can be written:

```
uudecode << 'EOF'
begin 644 file
$``$"`P``
`
end
EOF
```

(that output being obtained by running `uuencode file < some-file` where `some-file` contains that particular content).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a "here document".

```
cat >my_file <<__EOF__
RZW"a4k6[)b!^"%*X6EvF
__EOF__
```

When the shell sees the `<<foo` syntax, it remembers what `foo` is and continues reading until it sees `foo` on a line by itself.  Then it passes everything it read (except for `foo`) to the program's standard input.

Comment: That variant (with the delimiter not quoted) still has issues with `$`, backtick and backslash.

Answer (score 0):

To generate something to use as a command line argument, put it into a variable (or something else that you can ensure it gets into a *word* — then a single *argument* that gets passed to `printf`), then let bash/ksh93 do the rest.

```
# Reading from stdin
# pbpaste | bash -c '
printf echo\ %q\\n "$(cat)"
# ' | pbcopy
# Then paste it into your script and echo happily.
# Maybe I should use the `read' builtin instead..
```

Comment: Also in `zsh`. Note that it removes all trailing newline characters and adds one. It won't work with NUL characters except with `zsh`. You probably don't want to use `echo` here as you'll have trouble with values like `-n`/`-e` or containing backslash depending on the `echo` implementation or the environment.